# Checking if field has changed

Tags: apex, map

I need to check that a picklist field = "Active" and that it's previous value did not equal "Active" (only need to fire when this one field has changed).  I am attempting to do this with the following line:

```
if (P.Project_Status__c == 'Active' && P.Opportunity__c != Null && oldProjectMap.get(P.Project_Status__c) != 'Active')
```

But am receiving the error: "Comparison arguments must be compatible types: Project__c, String"

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my entire class

```
public class ProjectUtil {
    public static void UpdateOppStage (List<Project__c> Projects, map<id,Project__c> oldProjectMap) {
        Set<Id> ActiveProjectOpps = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> CompleteProjectOpps = new Set<Id>();
        //update
        if (oldProjectMap != null){
            for (Project__c P : Projects) {
            if (P.Project_Status__c == 'Active' && P.Opportunity__c != Null && oldProjectMap.get(P.Project_Status__c) != 'Active'){
                ActiveProjectOpps.add(P.Opportunity__c);
            }
            else if (P.Project_Status__c == 'Complete' && P.Opportunity__c != Null){
                CompleteProjectOpps.add(P.Opportunity__c);
            }   
        }
        }
        // insert 
        else if (oldProjectMap == null){
            for (Project__c P : Projects) {
            if (P.Project_Status__c == 'Active' && P.Opportunity__c != Null){
                ActiveProjectOpps.add(P.Opportunity__c);
            }
            else if (P.Project_Status__c == 'Complete' && P.Opportunity__c != Null){
                CompleteProjectOpps.add(P.Opportunity__c);
            }   
        }
        }

        List <Opportunity> ActiveOppsToUpdate = [SELECT id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE id in:ActiveProjectOpps];
        List <Opportunity> CompleteOppsToUpdate = [SELECT id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE id in:CompleteProjectOpps];

        for (Opportunity item: ActiveOppsToUpdate){
            item.StageName = 'Delivery';
        }
        for (Opportunity item: CompleteOppsToUpdate){
            item.StageName = 'Post Delivery Internal Meeting';
        }

        update ActiveOppsToUpdate;
        update CompleteOppsToUpdate;
        }
 }
```

Comment: Get(p.id).Project_Status__c ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from calling get is the value type of the map (Project__c). This means you still need to reference a field to compare to. Also, since the key type of map is ID, you also need to get the record by its ID.

```
if (P.Project_Status__c == 'Active' && P.Opportunity__c != Null && oldProjectMap.get(P.id).Project_Status__c != 'Active')
```